# Is there a way to know if a Windows 11 installation is a clean one or an update from a previous Windows?

Tags: windows-11

I believe the question is pretty straightforward.

Imagine you start a computer running Windows 11.  Is there a way to know for sure if it was a clean installation rather than an update over a previous Windows version?

Comment: Sometimes, but not always, the upgrade installer will create a `windows.old` folder, which is a giveaway. This folder won't exist on a clean install.

Comment: What problem are you attempting to solve exactly?

Comment: @Ramhound I want to check if the Windows instance running inside a Windows Sandbox on an upgraded Windows 11 has any information from the previous version or not.

Comment: It won’t because there isn’t any difference